# my Android Studio weather app not working on phone, but works in Android Studio emulator

Tags: android-studio, jsonobjectrequest

When i start app in emulator, its work properly, but when i install it on phone(I tested it on 2 of my friends phones), its not working like it should

I think the problem is with permissions stuff, but im not sure. Also it could be problem with JsonObjectRequest. So when i enter city name in my phone, i recieve "aaaaaaa, enter city name" from Response.ErrorListener()

There some code, **MainActivity:**

```
package com.example.weatherapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RelativeLayout homeRL;
    private ProgressBar loadingPB;
    private TextView cityNameTV, temperatureTV,conditionTV;
    private RecyclerView weatherRV;
    private TextInputEditText cityEdt;
    private ImageView backIV, iconIV, searchIV;
    private ArrayList<WeatherRVModal> weatherRVModalArrayList;
    private WeatherRVAdapter weatherRVAdapter;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private int PERMISSION_CODE=1;
    private String cityName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        homeRL = findViewById(R.id.idRLHome);
        loadingPB = findViewById(R.id.idPBLoading);
        cityNameTV = findViewById(R.id.idTVCityName);
        temperatureTV = findViewById(R.id.idTVTemprature);
        conditionTV = findViewById(R.id.idTVCondition);
        weatherRV = findViewById(R.id.idRVWeather);
        cityEdt = findViewById(R.id.idEdtCity);
        backIV = findViewById(R.id.idIVBack);
        iconIV = findViewById(R.id.idIVIcon);
        searchIV = findViewById(R.id.idIVSearch);
        weatherRVModalArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        weatherRVAdapter = new WeatherRVAdapter(this,weatherRVModalArrayList);
        weatherRV.setAdapter(weatherRVAdapter);

        locationManager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_CODE);

        }

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        //cityName = "London";
        //getWeatherInfo(cityName);
        if (location != null) {
            cityName = getCityName(location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
            getWeatherInfo(cityName);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"invalid location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        searchIV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //String city = cityEdt.getText().toString();
                String city = cityEdt.getText().toString();
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, city, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (city.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter your city name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    cityNameTV.setText(city);
                    getWeatherInfo(city);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
       public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            if (requestCode==PERMISSION_CODE) {
                if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please grant permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }

    private String getCityName(double longitude, double latitude){
        String cityName = "Not found";
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude, 10);

            for (Address adr : addresses) {
                if (adr!=null) {
                    String city = adr.getLocality();
                    if (city!=null && !city.equals("")){
                        cityName = city;
                    } else {
                        Log.d("TAG", "CITY NOT FOUND");
                        Toast.makeText(this, "User City Not Found...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cityName;
    }

    private void getWeatherInfo(String cityName) {
        String url = "http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=978870d191bb464f997175225221411&q="+cityName+"&days=1&aqi=yes&alerts=yes";
        cityNameTV.setText(cityName);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                loadingPB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                homeRL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                weatherRVModalArrayList.clear();

                try {
                            String temperature = response.getJSONObject("current").getString("temp_c");
                            temperatureTV.setText(temperature + "°C");
                            int isDay = response.getJSONObject("current").getInt("is_day");
                            String condition = response.getJSONObject("current").getJSONObject("condition").getString("text");
                            String conditionIcon = response.getJSONObject("current").getJSONObject("condition").getString("icon");
                            Picasso.get().load("http:".concat(conditionIcon)).into(iconIV);
                            conditionTV.setText(condition);
                            if (isDay == 1) {
                                Picasso.get().load("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1623949366895-4d7e63f08037?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=735&q=80").into(backIV);
                            } else {
                                Picasso.get().load("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505322022379-7c3353ee6291?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80").into(backIV);
                            }

                            JSONObject forecastObj = response.getJSONObject("forecast");
                            JSONObject forecast0 = forecastObj.getJSONArray("forecastday").getJSONObject(0);
                            JSONArray hourArray = forecast0.getJSONArray("hour");

                            for (int i=0; i<hourArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject hourObj = hourArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String time = hourObj.getString("time");
                                String temper = hourObj.getString("temp_c");
                                String img = hourObj.getJSONObject("condition").getString("icon");
                                String wind = hourObj.getString("wind_kph");
                                weatherRVModalArrayList.add(new WeatherRVModal(time, temper, img, wind));
                    }
                    weatherRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"aaaaaaa, enter city name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@drawable/cloudy"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/cloudy"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.WeatherApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**WeatherRVModal**:

```
package com.example.weatherapp;

public class WeatherRVModal {

    private String time;
    private String temperature;
    private String icon;
    private String windSpeed;

    public WeatherRVModal(String time, String temperature, String icon, String windSpeed) {
        this.time = time;
        this.temperature = temperature;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.windSpeed = windSpeed;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    public void setTemperature(String temperature) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getWindSpeed() {
        return windSpeed;
    }

    public void setWindSpeed(String windSpeed) {
        this.windSpeed = windSpeed;
    }
}
```

**WeatherRVAdapter:**

```
package com.example.weatherapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class WeatherRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WeatherRVAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<WeatherRVModal> weatherRVModalArrayList;

    public WeatherRVAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<WeatherRVModal> weatherRVModalArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.weatherRVModalArrayList = weatherRVModalArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public WeatherRVAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.weather_rv_item,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WeatherRVAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        WeatherRVModal modal = weatherRVModalArrayList.get(position);
        holder.temperatureTV.setText(modal.getTemperature() + "°C");
        Picasso.get().load("http:".concat(modal.getIcon())).into(holder.conditionIV);
        holder.windTV.setText(modal.getWindSpeed()+"Км/ч");
        SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
        SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
        try {
            Date t = input.parse(modal.getTime());
            holder.timeTV.setText(output.format(t));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return weatherRVModalArrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView windTV,temperatureTV,timeTV;
        private ImageView conditionIV;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            windTV=itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTVWindSpeed);
            temperatureTV=itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTVTemprature);
            timeTV=itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTVTime);
            conditionIV=itemView.findViewById(R.id.idIVCondition);

        }
    }
}
```

Im new in Android Studio so if I have not attached something say and I will do it

Comment: If you deploy it to your phone. Please long-press the icon on your homescreen and go to app info. Then to permissions and try to enable all the permissions. Close and reopen the app and check wether the problems went away.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging Your Code I Found **JSONExceptio**n In Your **HTTP** api requests. `volley.Response`

TO Solve This Problem Use ( **HTTPS** )

**https**://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=978870d191bb464f997175225221411&q="+cityName+"&days=1&aqi=yes&alerts=yes

Thanks.